# Find max and min for even and odd numbers

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
 ID     numbers
 1        12 
 2        4
 3        13
 4        8
 5        9
 6        4
```

I want to find largest and smallest odd and even number in column and tag it

```
 ID     numbers      Tag
 1        12         Largest even
 2        4          Smallest even 
 3        13         Largest odd 
 4        8          
 5        9          Smallest odd
 6        4          Smallest even
```

I tried doing following

```
 df$tag <- ifelse(which.max(df$numbers %% 2 == 0),"Largest even",
                 ifelse(which.min(df$numbers %% 2 == 0),"Smallest even",
                       ifelse(which.max(df$numbers %% 2 != 0),"Largest odd",
                             ifelse(which.min(df$numbers %% 2 != 0),"Smallest odd",
```

It does not work the way I wanted.

Comment: What happens when there is only 1 even number?

Comment: In my case it will not happen. I will atleast have two even or odd numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr, make a group of odds/evens then get min max per group.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(grp = if_else(numbers %% 2 == 0, "even", "odd")) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(ID, numbers,
         Tag = paste0(if_else(numbers == min(numbers), paste("Smallest", grp), ""),
                      if_else(numbers == max(numbers), paste("Largest", grp), ""))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#      ID numbers           Tag
#   <int>   <int>         <chr>
# 1     1      12  Largest even
# 2     2       4 Smallest even
# 3     3      13   Largest odd
# 4     4       8              
# 5     5       9  Smallest odd
# 6     6       4 Smallest even
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(grp = if_else(numbers %% 2 == 0, "even", "odd")) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(ID, numbers,
         Tag = paste0(if_else(numbers == min(numbers), "Smallest ", ""),
                      if_else(numbers == max(numbers), "Largest ", ""),
                      grp)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#      ID numbers           Tag
#   <int>   <int>         <chr>
# 1     1      12  Largest even
# 2     2       4 Smallest even
# 3     3      13   Largest odd
# 4     4       8          even
# 5     5       9  Smallest odd
# 6     6       4 Smallest even
```

Comment: Is it possible to print even or odd number where there is blank ? like in the 4th row it should print `even`

Comment: @zx8754 I replaced it with `grp` but it gives me `oddLargest odd,evenLargest even
` something like this

Comment: @Neil updated to show odd/even when they are not largest or smallest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Tag := paste(c("", "Smallest", "Largest")[1 + (numbers == min(numbers)) +
     2*(numbers == max(numbers))], grp), .(grp = c('even', 'odd')[(numbers%%2)+1])]

df1
#   ID numbers           Tag
#1:  1      12  Largest even
#2:  2       4 Smallest even
#3:  3      13   Largest odd
#4:  4       8          even
#5:  5       9  Smallest odd
#6:  6       4 Smallest even
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Appreciated